# Simulation of Hard Core Model

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, markov-process, simulation

i already learned about Hard core Model and i know the steps Using markov chain monte carlo (MCMC) to realise it.But i don't know how to make/do a Simulation of Hard code Model in practice.

Can someone help me to make the code for it ? and wich tools/program can i use to do it.

thank you for your Help !

Comment: Maybe you can spell out what this model is and what simulation scheme you have in mind to use for it essentially is. In particular seeing as you mention MCs, it should be clear whether your problem is continuous vs. discrete time and continuous vs. discrete space.

Comment: yes , I'm working in  discrete with discrete time.My Model is  a graph with vertex set V=(v_{1},...v_{n) } and edge set E = (e_{1}...,e_{n}) and we have to assign randomly the value 0 or 1 to each of the vertices, in such a way that no  two adjacent vertices (ie.not two vertices  that share an edge) both take the value 1.For more detail  you can see please the following link : http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/stochastik/lehre/ss06/markov/skript_engl/node34.html

Comment: Alright. And you want to sample admissible configurations according to the uniform distribution on all admissible configurations? If so then it seems to me that the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm is perfectly well-suited to your situation, you just have to pick some method for generating candidates (which is always more art than science).

Comment: MH is also very easy to implement.

Comment: yes you have totaly right.The problem for me is , that i don't know how to do the implementation in R or Python or in an other Program that help me to write the code and do animation for the hard core Model.I will be very thankful If you have some advices or sources, that help me to do the simulation.

Comment: As I said MH is very simple to implement. Many sources describing it mathematically will have pseudocode. The main thing you will need is a way to actually generate your candidates, but in this situation that should really not be very hard (for example you can just flip the state of one site chosen uniformly at random to get a candidate state, which can be done easily with random integer functions).